# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/posix/POSIXHandler while starting up cassandra based spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, spring-data-cassandra

When I startup my SpringBoot app (where I am using Cassandra as the DB), I get the following trace during startup :

```
Could not register Graph extensions; this is normal if Tinkerpop was explicitly excluded from classpath
Unable to load JNR native implementation. This could be normal if JNR is excluded from the classpath
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/posix/POSIXHandler
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.os.Native$LibcLoader.load(Native.java:42)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.os.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:59)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock.getInstance(Clock.java:34)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.MonotonicTimestampGenerator.buildClock(MonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:109)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.MonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(MonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.AtomicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicTimestampGenerator.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.Reflection.buildFromConfig(Reflection.java:246)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.Reflection.buildFromConfig(Reflection.java:108)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.DefaultDriverContext.buildTimestampGenerator(DefaultDriverContext.java:373)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.DefaultDriverContext.getTimestampGenerator(DefaultDriverContext.java:759)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.init(DefaultSession.java:349)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.access$1100(DefaultSession.java:300)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.lambda$init$0(DefaultSession.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.run(PromiseTask.java:106)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoop.run(DefaultEventLoop.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnr.posix.POSIXHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

The application starts fine, but is there a workaround to avoid/suppress this?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this was asked a long time ago, but I just ran across the same issue and resolved it myself, so I'm posting the solution here.

In my build.gradle file I added the following import

```
compile "com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:3.1.15"
```

Comment: This suggestion solved my issue, but i am using maven, so pasting the maven command
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jnr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnr-posix</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.15</version>
        </dependency>